# Jenkins: How to keep promoted builds for ever?

Tags: jenkins

When a build is promoted to production, I want to keep this build forever so I could rollback if needed. I can manually click the keep this build forever button. But I wonder if there is a way to automatically keep any promoted build forever?

Comment: Don't keep them in Jenkins then. Use a dedicated software library (eg:a dedicated volume w/limited write ability, or artifact repository.(Nexus, Artifactory)."Keep this build forever" is only forever as long as the job remains; delete the job and poof.

Comment: Agree with Ian. The source of truth should be a Git repo, an artifact repo, an image registry... probably you are promoting an app identified with a version (i.e: v1.0.2) so with that, you can reproduce the promotion as many times you want (i.e: A job to re-deploy a given version/commit hash, like v1.0.1). Jobs are volatile.

Comment: What's important to me in that build is the git commit number. My build takes 15 minutes to finish so I store the built file some where so rolling back or promote will be done in seconds. I don't mean to keep them forever, that was just the button's name. I just want to them to live longer than those failed or never promoted builds. It's not the end of the world even if they are deleted, it's just it takes longer to build that specific commit from scratch.