# Jenkins: How to keep promoted builds for ever? (Please don't close)

Tags: jenkins

When a build is promoted to production, I want to keep this build forever so I could rollback if needed. I can manually click the keep this build forever button. But I wonder if there is a way to automatically keep any promoted build forever?

I ask this question again because the same question ([Jenkins: How to keep promoted builds for ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64298398/jenkins-how-to-keep-promoted-builds-for-ever)) was closed without a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

In jenkins if you are using `maven` to build your application there is an option to do that:
[image: Jenkins configuration for maven]

If your jenkins does not have that it means that you need to install plugin for it.
`Gradle` propably has the same configuration.